# Root Phone Without Unlocking Lockscreen

Tags: rooting

Is it possible to root a phone without knowing a the phone's pattern/pin/password? This question isn't because I need to root a phone without a pattern/pin/password but because I was curious and thinking about the process. I'm assuming that you would have to put the image on an external SD card and then load it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** Yes, it is possible. Different techniques can be used for this purpose (some of them are described e.g. in *Andrew Hoog's* book [Android Forensics: Investigation, Analysis and Mobile Security for Google Android](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1597496510)). It especially gets easy when USB Debugging is turned on.

**Long answer:** Please forgive me if I don't give this. Just a hint: There are exploits, and there are custom recovery images...

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I was looking for (yes/no with explanation)